# Docker MonoRepo with Storybook 'cannot find module react/package.json'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, storybook, lerna

I'm pretty new to docker, and today I've tried to dockerize our lerna monorepo using the following settings:

dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.13.1-alpine

# Add node modules bin to path
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV PATH /app/packages/core/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /app

# Install app deps
COPY ./ ./

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn bootstrap
RUN cd packages/core && yarn install && cd ./node_modules/react && yarn link && cd ../../../../ && yarn link react
RUN cd packages/core && yarn build

CMD yarn storybook ${STORY_FILTER}
```

docker-compose

```
services:
  packages:
    container_name: packages
    image: packages
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - '.:/app'
        - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
        - 6006:6006
    environment:
        - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
        - STORY_FILTER=packages/core/stories/forms/index
```

Basic file structure:

```
+--storybook
+--packages
|  -+core
|   --package.json
|  -+styles
|   --package.json
+--dockerfile
+--docker-compose
+--package.json
+--lerna.json
```

I'm currently seeing an error which states 'cannot find module react/package.json'